# WIndows 8 running IIS 8 need 7

Tags: webserver, iis

We have a Laptop the will be acting as a webserver for a lightweight medical imaging source for a site that will require mobility. We chose a Lenovo flex for the job. When installing the the software that also created a website on IIS 8 it generates an error on the landing page that its incompatible the error code relates to the software not being compatible with IIS 8 (it was built for IIS 7 or later.

Is there any sort of way to run an IIS 7 site on IIS 8? I did not see a classic mode anywhere.

Comment: having worked with IIS for a long time, I can't say I've seen many Sites that care what version you are using. Most of the time the version differances mostly come down to how you configure the server-side scripting for the site, so I would not generally say that a site is "an IIS X site", I would say it is a site that has been configured for IIS X. I recommend attempting to convert the configuration to use the new server. Without knowning anything about the site server-side, I couldn't tell you any more, but there are common ways to convert from classic to integrated app pools, etc.

Comment: [IIS 8 has a classic mode.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingOldAppsFromIIS6ToIIS8AndWhyClassicModeExists.aspx) Where did you check?

Comment: @Op, what kind of web technologies is the site made of (eg: PHP, ASP.Net, ASP classic, HTML/Javascript only, etc. )?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any web applications that runs on IIS7 but not on IIS8, all the technologies and features are still there. There are no breaking changes between IIS7 and 8.x.

There are just some additional features which don't break existing sites.

So if an IIS7 webApp doesn't work on IIS8, it has to do with the configuration of the server, ApplicationPool or site.